# How to create dynamic forms for dynamic survey and how to store that form's value?

Tags: php

I want to make application like "**wufoo.com-Online form and surveys**". How can I create dynamic forms for dynamic survey.

How can I handle that dynamic form's value into DB? Can anyone give me an idea how can I should manage dynamic surveys?

Comment: The question is much too broad. What do you have a problem with? database design? PHP programming?

Answer (score 1):

What you asked, is about to analyse a complete project ;)

From database view, You will need different tables in your database.

1. **tbl_forms** (to store user-defined form templates)
2. **tbl_controls** (to store different availabe web controls like textbox or radio button)
3. **tbl_questions** (to store each user-defined form question)
4. **tbl_valid_answers** (to store the corrent answer for each defiend question)
5. **tbl_answers** (to store givven answers)
6. **tbl_users** (to store your questioner information)
7. **tbl_visitors** (to store your forms visitors information)

And I'm sure you will need to lost of other information and elements.

Comment: What's up with the tbl_ prefix? Are you afraid of some virus which would hide himself in the middle of your tables? :-)